# Capistrano current/ directory doesn't get created

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, devops

The current directory doesn't get created by capistrano when trying to deploy for the first time.

I try to deploy:check the project and everything is just fine, but when I actually deploy the process ends up in error:

```
DEBUG [8d5bfb3a]    Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'
cap aborted!
if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'" 1>&2; false; fi exit status: 1
if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'" 1>&2; false; fi stdout: Nothing written
if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'" 1>&2; false; fi stderr: Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:98:in `exit_status='
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:142:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/sshDEBUG [ac4ea3f3] Finished in 0.053 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO unicorn is running...
/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/net-ssh-2.9.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:166:in `block in _execute'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:75:in `within'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/capistrano3-unicorn-0.1.1/lib/capistrano3/tasks/unicorn.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ec-api/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => unicorn:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'" 1>&2; false; fi exit status: 1
if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'" 1>&2; false; fi stdout: Nothing written
if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'" 1>&2; false; fi stderr: Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api/current'
```

From my experience it's normally caused by a previous problem that didn't let the deploy end, but I can't really see any noticeable exception or error (but I might be missing something obvious).

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application,                 'reputationmonitor-api'

set :scm,                         :git
set :repo_url,                    'git@github.com:thefoolsrl/EngagementConsole-API'
set :ssh_options,                 {user: 'deployer', forward_agent: true}

set :stages,                      %w(staging demo production)
set :default_stage,               'staging'

set :user,                        'deployer'
set :group,                       'deployer'

set :deploy_to,                   '/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api'

set :format,                      :pretty
set :log_level,                   :debug

set :linked_files,                %w{config/database.yml config/redis.yml config/unicorn.rb}
set :linked_dirs,                 %w{bin log sockets tmp/pids tmp/sockets}

set :redis_config, "#{shared_path}/config/redis.yml"
set :unicorn_config_path, "#{deploy_to}/shared/config/unicorn.rb"

set :sidekiq_timeout, 30
set :sidekiq_options, " -e #{fetch(:stage)} -C #{current_path}/config/sidekiq.yml -r #{current_path}/config/environment.rb -L #{shared_path}/log/sidekiq.log"

set :rvm_ruby_version,            '2.1.1'

set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Start application'
  task :start do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "sudo service nginx start"
    end
  end

  desc 'Stop application' do
    task :stop do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        execute 'sudo service nginx stop'
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute 'sudo service nginx reload'
    end
  end

  task :migrate do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within release_path do
        with rack_env: fetch(:rack_env) do
          execute :rake, "db:migrate"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

namespace :remote_invoker do

  desc 'Restart RemoteCallbackInvoker Daemon'
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within release_path do
        with rack_env: fetch(:rack_env) do
          execute :ruby, "./scripts/callback_invoker restart"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:migrate'
after "deploy:updated", "deploy:cleanup" 
after 'deploy:migrate', 'unicorn:restart'
after 'unicorn:restart', 'remote_invoker:restart'
```

Does anybody have any clue what can I look to debug this?

Comment: Did you created a folder named `reputationmonitor-api` on the server? and also make sure that you create it the right location that you have specified on the script like:  `/home/deployer/apps/reputationmonitor-api`

Comment: Of course, deploy:check does it

Comment: @ngw did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: I did, but the problem can be pretty much everything: it was failing before symlinking the current dir. I suggest you go backwards and repeat every capistrano command in your production/staging shell until you find what's wrong that makes the deploy fail.

Comment: I might add that the link depends heavily upon your specific web server setup. I was getting the same types of failures until I went through and made all the links direct. You may have to go to your desired destination folder, and run `pwd` to get this, but after I had set it up, things were working fine.

Comment: Same problem here deploy:check helped me. My error was due to failed attempt to connect to gitlab server.